# PlotBy instruction not working on xlColumnStacked100 Charts

Tags: excel, vba

I need to change the subtype of a Chart programmatically. I attach an image of what the code generates by default and what I need.

My VBA code is:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(297, xlColumnStacked100).Select
    ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlRows
```

But it does nothing, I also tried ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlColumns also but the chart does not change. I can't do this graphically:

[image]

But if the chart is xlColumnStacked instead of xlColumnStacked100, this way works (ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlRows). I need it to work on xlColumnStacked100 too or the equivalent on this chart.

Macro recorder does not log this changes.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the Macro Recorder?

Comment: yes, it does not record this kind of changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tests, I tried the same code on another computers and it simply worked, so I think it could failed because of something on %appdata% or similar. I'm restoring the factory defaults on that PC.